# Assign or Change sjg grid title dynamically

Tags: jsp, grid, struts2-jquery

Is it possible to change or assign sjg grid title dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#GridId").jqGrid('setLabel', 'valueId', 'NewLabel');
```

valueId is name of the grid column